# edit template not displaying on edit route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I would like to edit users. I am following this tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

I have a button in `user.hbs` to edit the user:

`<button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>` and below it is an `{{outlet}}`

When click it I'm directed to `/index.html#/users/4/edit` but my `user.edit.hbs` template does not show up

Here's `userEditRoute.js`:

```
App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){ 
    return this.modelFor('user');
  }
});
```

And the `userController.js`:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    edit: function(){
      this.transitionToRoute('user.edit');
    }
});
```

Why won't the `user.edit.hbs` display?

Comment: Are you using some build tool like: ember app kit, ember tools etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you configured your router, but a url with `/users/<someid>/edit` expect  `this.transitionToRoute('user.edit', someObjectOrId);`

Comment: i have that code in `userController.js` (posted above). If I pass `user` as a second argument I get the error "user is not defined" and it doesn't direct to `/users/<someid>/edit`

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in the following way.
Kindly check this [BIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ASaViNe/2#/users)