# display edit template directly in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to emberjs. I am overwhelms by all complex concepts like routers, controllers, etc. and so I am repeatedly asking noob questions on SO.

**Problem: I want to show edit template as outlet in users template....without using user template**

---

**Method 1**

This is my 'users' template. The data is showing correctly. When I select the 'Edit' link the profile of the selected user is shown below the table.

http://pastebin.com/SEUWFuPi

This is my routes file

http://pastebin.com/EpdZU2Tk

However, since I am showing the all the users' info in the table, I do not want to show the user profile below the table. I directly want to show the user/edit template there.

But in my 'users' template, when I change

```
<td>{{#linkTo 'user' this}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{#linkTo 'user/edit' this}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</td>
```

Then even /#/users fails to render. I get the error:
**Assertion failed: The attempt to link-to route 'user/edit.index' failed.**

---

**Method 2**

I followed the code given in the question part of this post
[edit template not displaying on edit route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326145/edit-template-not-displaying-on-edit-route)

I copy / pasted the code from the question part....so I am not repeating it here. **The difference with that post and my code is that I have put the code for the button in my 'users' template, whereas the other poster has put it in the 'user' template.**

But when I click the Edit button I get the error that **'edit' action was not handled.**

As far as I know, the users/edit route is nested inside the users/:user_id route, therefore I am unable to access it directly. However, I want to display the edit template directly. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you put your code in that jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/. It already have all dependencies. After some edition in the jsbin is generated a url, so you can share that code in a runnable environment with us.

Comment: The code uses a CodeIgniter web service....so it would not run in jsbin